50% of my request to Squid used as a proxy and setup with BasicAuth receive a 407, the other half works as expected. Why?
I have a Java application that needs to ping third party websites. To make it safer, I use Squid as a proxy:
+-----------+     +-------------+     +--------------------+
| Java App. |---->| Squid Proxy |---->| Third party server |
+-----------+     +-------------+     +--------------------+

The system seems to work as expected, but when I look at the Squid Proxy logs, I see a ton of 407 errors. Is that normal? It seems to be a near 50/50 ratio (a little more 200 than 407). I'm wondering whether the Java proxy code is not always sending the credentials which would explain that many 407 errors.
The Java code uses a RequestBuilder like so:
import org.asynchttpclient.AsyncHttpClient;
import org.asynchttpclient.Realm;
import org.asynchttpclient.Request;
import org.asynchttpclient.RequestBuilder;
import org.asynchttpclient.proxy.ProxyServer;
import org.asynchttpclient.proxy.ProxyType;

[...]

private final AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient;

[...]

var reqBuilder = new RequestBuilder(GET);
reqBuilder.setUrl(url);
var realm = new Realm.Builder(proxyUser, proxySecret)
              .setScheme(Realm.AuthScheme.BASIC);
var proxy = new ProxyServer.Builder(proxyHost, proxyPort)
             .setSecuredPort(proxyPort)
             .setProxyType(ProxyType.HTTP)
             .setRealm(realm));
reqBuilder.setProxyServer(proxy);
Request request = reqBuilder.build();
return asyncHttpClient
    .executeRequest(request)
    .toCompletableFuture()
    .handle(
        (r, t) -> {
          return (Response) Response.ok();
        });

_  Note: I removed the error handling to make the code look straight forward._
Finally, the Squid configuration has these lines about basic auth:
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/squid.htpasswd
auth_param basic realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated

Do you see anything wrong with my setup?

I actually found out that the Java implementation of Realm calls this non-Preemptive vs Preemptive. The first one does not send any credentials in an abundance of precaution.
What I want, to avoid all of those 407 and double GET requests is to use preemptive. Since this is on a LAN, it is safe. Here is the one extra line:
  var realm = new Realm.Builder(proxyUser, proxySecret)
              .setScheme(Realm.AuthScheme.BASIC)
              .setUsePreemptiveAuth(true);  // ← add this one line

I did not have to change anything in the Squid configuration file. The defaults worked on that end.
